# Change "close" hyperlink when sharing docs

Tags: support, documentation, design

When sharing docs it is hard to read the "close" hyperlink.  Can we change this to white?

[image]

Comment: PS: This is a freehand square - squares are never used and kind of lonely...we should all make a habit of squaring more often.

Comment: Same for the character count of the downvote explanation popup's textarea (http://i.imgur.com/bU8hEp8.png)

Comment: @SeinopSys - Edit my post to add it and include a screenshot with a square around the issue.

Comment: If I wasn't >2k such an edit would be rejected as conflicting with the author's intent. It'd probably be better as a separate question but I don't care enough to bother doing it.

Comment: @SeinopSys - You must care...this is stackoverflow..I mean its STACKOVERFLOW :).

Comment: @SeinopSys Long ago, in docs-beta, I posted a question about that — I think it should be a modal (like flag) instead of that popup.